# “blob” links are blocked Livewire azure

Tags: php, laravel, azure, google-chrome, laravel-livewire

i have an issue with chrome, whenever i try to download the file it block show this error
[image: “blob” links are blocked]

here is my view:

```
 <button wire:click="downloadResults" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
       <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
          Download all results
 </button>
```

And my controller

```
 public function downloadResults(){
 
    return Response::download($this->downloadResults);
        
}
```

Comment: I think you may have a naming conflict. i.e. please check - you may have `downloadResults` as a function and a property variable? Would need more code to know exactly what is going on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you the issues was due to the GTM i comment it and the error gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently experienced this issue and it turned out to be an issue with Google Tag Manager.

Comment out Google Analytics and it will work.

Update to the latest recommended Google Analytics snippet

[How to check for live issues with google tag manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72031870/how-to-check-for-live-issues-with-google-tag-manager)

Comment: Thank you so much, the issue came due to this reason